# Rails for nested array hidden input field in form (Haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

What would be a better "Rails way" of doing it

```
  - shops.map(&:id).each do |id|
    <input id="p_shop_ids_#{id}" name="p[shop_ids][]" type="hidden" value="#{id}" />
```

I recently read that in Haml is in this sense downwards compatible. But it feels like it should be done with the rails checkbox helper instead

Comment: `- @shops.map(&:id).each do |id|
  = hidden_field_tag "shop_ids[]", id`

Comment: @Sontya I explicitly need the array nested in  'p' .. which wouldn't be inlcuded in your solution. With one way I tried I ended up having p[shop_ids[]] instead of p[shop_ids][]

Comment: It's an hash key inside of the params hash who contains a hash with one kind of param attributes (there are other kinds of param attributes, so it's better to organize it in sub-hashes).. the params that the controller receives look something like this
{"utf8"=>"✓", "p"=>{"country_id"=>"1", shop_ids: ["1", "2"], ...}, ... }

Comment: - @shops.map(&:id).each do |id| = hidden_field_tag "p[shop_ids][]", id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Sontya's comment (thanks!!)

```
- shops.map(&:id).each do |id|
  = hidden_field_tag "p[shop_ids][]", id, id: "p_shop_ids_#{id}"
```

produces the correct output (I had to add the id-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hidden field helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field).

Comment: yes, and how exactly can I manage to combine the array thing into the nestedness (p[shop_ids][])